# Как удалить/заменить символы в строке в JAVA используя Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

У меня есть exel файл в котором 2 колонки: номер телефона и имена.
Например
**380677777055 - ОЛЕГ**
И в номере телефона бывают ошибки когда вместо "0" стоит буква "О" или запятая. 
Как мне вывести в .txt файл все значения без ошибок?
Не получается из за того что меняет символы и в строке с именами.

```
public class ExelToTxt {

public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
public static DataFormatter ndt = new DataFormatter();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fisStat = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/ё/Desktop/ТРА.xls");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("my4.txt");

    Workbook wbStat = new HSSFWorkbook(fisStat);

    fisStat.close();

    Sheet sheetInputStat = wbStat.getSheetAt(0);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    int i = 0;

    for (Row row : sheetInputStat) {

        Cell cellNumber = row.getCell(i);
        Cell cellInquiry = row.getCell(i + 1);
        Cell cellInquiry1 = row.getCell(i + 2);
        Cell cellInquiry2 = row.getCell(i + 3);
        Cell cellInquiry3 = row.getCell(i + 4);
        Cell cellInquiry4 = row.getCell(i + 5);
        Cell cellInquiry5 = row.getCell(i + 6);
        Cell cellInquiry6 = row.getCell(i + 7);
        Cell cellInquiry7 = row.getCell(i + 8);
        Cell cellInquiry8 = row.getCell(i + 9);
        Cell cellInquiry9 = row.getCell(i + 10);

        NullVerify(cellNumber,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry1,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry2,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry3,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry4,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry5,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry6,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry7,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry8,sb);
        NullVerify(cellInquiry9,sb);

        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    }

    fos.flush();
    fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
    fos.close();
}

static void replace(char[] arr, char find, char replace) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        while (arr[i] == find) {
            arr[i] = replace;
        }
        while (arr[i] == ',') {
            arr[i] =  '!';
        }
    }
}

static void NullVerify(Cell CellName,StringBuffer stb) {
if (CellName != null) {
    stb.append(getCellText(CellName));
    stb.append("\t");

}
}

// берем строковое значение из любой ячейки
public static String getCellText(Cell cell) {

    String result = "";


    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        result = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            result = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
            result = ndt.formatCellValue(cell);
        }
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        result = Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        result = cell.getCellFormula().toString();
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Напишите проблемный участок кода

Comment: Написал метод которым я пытаюсь изменить ситуацию, но он меняет все буквы "О" на нули

Comment: Зачем писать какой-то метод если String уже имплементирует replace?

Comment: в любом случае он поменяет все значения , а мне нужно только в столбике номеров телефона.

Comment: так передавайте ему только столбик с номером телефона. Проблема его получить?

Comment: Да, проблема в получении номеров и в последствии правильного размещения обоих столбиков в .txt файле, а именно через (line separator).

Comment: Вы писали: "У меня есть exel файл в котором 2 колонки: номер телефона и имена...". В чем проблема брать колонку только с номером телефона?

Comment: Мне нужно в txt файл переместить оба столбца только с редактированием номеров.

Comment: Добавьте код, где вы считываете столбцы, так станет удобнее Вам написать что куда передавать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = null;
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0])) {
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
}

DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
    String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    cell.setCellValue(value.replace("O", "0"));
}

try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[0])) {
    wb.write(out);
}
```

Comment: Тип данных в этом столбце NUMERIC.  Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell

Comment: @КонстантинКонстантин это усложняет задачу всего на две строки.

Comment: не работает, посмотрите мой код , он выводит все значения из Exel файла, но не редактирует. Как сделать так чтоб редактировал первый столбец

Comment: Что означает "не работает"? Ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: Ваш код плох и избыточен, его надо переписывать полностью, а не править. К тому же в нём нет ни одной строки отвечающей за изменение данных в ячейках или записи изменённой таблицы в файл.

Comment: Согласен с тем что код плох, но как смог. Я знаю что нет изменения данных в ячейках, потому что я не знаю как правильно сделать чтоб не сломать код и правильную последовательность записи в файл.